# compact (and aesthetically pleasing/professional looking) NAS case with 6-8 hot swap bays

Tags: case, nas

I'm looking for a case for my home NAS.

I'm thinking about 6-8 drives; I don't have a specific need for hot swap drives, I just like that design.

What I have in mind something like a FreeNAS Mini, but unfortunately buying a pre-assembled one would exceed my current budget.

[image: freenas mini]

Few clarifications:

- Why "professionally looking"? I'm going to keep it at home so I can't cringe every time I see it - "well designed" would be more in line with what I'm looking for but that I'm sure many would consider an ugly mess of LEDs and plexiglass as "well designed" [but hey, people could say the same of the black monoliths I love :-) ]
- Compact: I'm not looking for a desktop tower to convert into a NAS, I don't see the point in having a 50-liters beast around when I have no use for GPU/water cooling inside my case.
- Why not a Synology / Qnap NAS? I'm going to run FreeNAS OS on it, but otherwise I really like the look of their NAS.
- Ideally the hot swap drives would have LED that can be used to monitor the disk activity/state (I'm not sure how it would be to actually get it to work with the OS so this would be the least important feature).

Comment: That's a lot of hot swap bays. It's not quite what you want, but take a look at [my previous post](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8557/mini-itx-case-with-10-sata-hot-swap-bays/8577#8577) while I try and do some research. Do they need to be 3.5" bays, or will 2.5" work? How compact is "compact"?

Comment: Looks like finding 6 and 8 bay cases is a lot easier. I've got a number of options, but a couple of questions first. Would you prefer more rectangular or more square? Is cost a significant issue, and if so, what's your budget? Do you want a parts list with a full build or just a case recommendation?